# Prove that $(\mathbb{Q}^*, \times )$ is not cyclic (compare my solution to textbook solution)

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

The following is an exercise from "Guide to Abstract Algebra 1st Ed, Carol Whitehead"

> Prove that $(\mathbb{Q}^*, \times )$ is not cyclic.

**Question:** My own solution appears simpler than the textbook's solution. Which makes me ask where my solution is wrong.

---

**My Solution:**

Members of the group $G = (\mathbb{Q}^{*}, \times)$ take the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p \in \mathbb{Z}, q \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}$.

In a cyclic group, the generator $g \in G$ is such that $g^m = 1$, the identity element, where $m$ is the finite order of the generator $g$.

We can see straight away that $g^m = (\frac{p}{q})^m  = \frac{p^m}{q^m}\neq 1$ in general, except when $p=q$, the trivial case of the identity element.

Therefore the group is not cyclic.

---

**Textbook Solution:**

Suppose $(\mathbb{Q}^{*}, \times) = < \frac{a}{b} > $, where $a \in \mathbb{Z}, b \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$.

Then $\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Q} \implies \frac{1}{2} = (\frac{a}{b})^r$, for some $r \in \mathbb{Z} \implies a^r = 1 \implies a= ± 1$

.. which is clearly false, since, e.g., $\frac{2}{3} \in \mathbb{Q}^{*}$.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Q}^*$ isn't finite, there's no reason to show it isn't a finite cyclic group.  However, there are infinite cyclic groups (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$) so you haven't shown what you need to yet.  (Also, there is a case when $(p/q)^m = 1$ when $p\neq q$, so even that step isn't valid)

Comment: Notation: `\langle \frac{a}{b} \rangle` for better angle-brackets: $\langle \frac{a}{b} \rangle$

Answer (score 2):

> In a cyclic group, the generator $g \in G$ is such that $g^m = 1$, the identity element, where $m$ is the finite order of the generator $g$.

Nothing in the definition of a cyclic group implies the generator has finite order.  This is true about **finite** cyclic groups, but since $\mathbb{Q}^*$ is infinite, there's no reason to spend time checking whether it's a finite cyclic group.

It would suffice to stop there, since your initial plan of showing it's not a cyclic group by showing it's not a finite cyclic group is invalid, but the very next thing you say is also wrong:

> We can see straight away that $g^m = (\frac{p}{q})^m  = \frac{p^m}{q^m}\neq 1$ in general, except when $p=q$, the trivial case of the identity element.

There is one more element in $\mathbb{Q}^*$ with finite order.  If you can find it and show/note $\mathbb{Q}^*$ is infinite, then you will have an alternative, correct proof that $\mathbb{Q}^*$ isn't cyclic.

Comment: Thanks Brian - this has been helpful to surface my misunderstanding that a group is cyclic if the generator has finite order. For example $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition has a generator {1} but the order is not finite. In this specific example I note that $\mathbb{Q}^*$ under multiplication has element {-1} which has finite order because $(-1)^2=1$ the identity element, but the group's oder is not finite, hence it is not cyclic - correct?

Comment: @Penelope You probably need to fill in the details on why an infinite cyclic group can't have an element of finite order $> 1$, as I doubt this theorem was given in the text, but once you do that, the conclusion does follow.